# How to organize an array by putting its elements into different subsets in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I wanna organize a set of integers by putting prime numbers into one subset.
For example:

Input set:
`{2,4,6,7,11,6,3}.`

Desired result:

Prime numbers: `{2,7,11,3}.`

Non prime numbers: `{4,6,6}.`

This is my reasonable code that ended up with a ridiculous result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
 int i,j,n,a=0,b1=0,b2=0;
 printf(" Enter the number of elements in the set: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 int integer[n],nonPrime[n],prime[n];
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
     printf(" Enter #%d element of the set: ",i);
     scanf("%d",&integer[i-1]);
 }
 printf("\n The set is: {");
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
     printf("%d ",integer[i-1]);
 }
 printf("}");
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
     for(j=2;j<=integer[i-1]/2;j++) {
         if(integer[i-1]%j==0) {
             a=1;
             break;
         }
     }
     if(a==1) {
         integer[i-1]=nonPrime[i-1];
         b1++;

     }
     else {
         integer[i-1]=prime[i-1];
         b2++;

     }
 }
 printf("\n Prime numbers: { ");
 for(i=1;i<=b2;i++) {
     printf("%d ",prime[i-1]);
 }
 printf("}\n Non prime numbers: { ");
 for(i=1;i<=b1;i++) {
     printf("%d ",nonPrime[i-1]);
 }
 printf("} \n");

return 0;
}
 //HENG SOK MENG
```

The output:

```
 Enter the number of elements in the set: 6
 Enter #1 element of the set: 1
 Enter #2 element of the set: 3
 Enter #3 element of the set: 5
 Enter #4 element of the set: 7
 Enter #5 element of the set: 4
 Enter #6 element of the set: 6

 The set is: {1 3 5 7 4 6 }
 Prime numbers: { 1965421290 1965972381 718360966 32 }
 Non prime numbers: { 2686560 718361022 }

 Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.063 s
 Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: It would be easier to read if you added a text dump of your output to your question, instead of a picture :) SO doesn't like pictures of text.

Comment: I've included the output in text.

Comment: Why use `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`, why not just `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`? Then you can avoid indexing `[i-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is slightly wrong. This code shows that your loops can be simplified to `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`, which will allow indexing over `[i]`, instead of `[i-1]`.

You can use a helper function like `isprime(int n)` to check for prime numbers in the `integers[n]` array, then add to the other corresponding partitioned arrays accordingly.

This code segment demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isprime(int n);

int 
main(void) {
    int n, i, primecnt = 0, nonprimecnt = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in the set: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid entry\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int integers[n], prime[n], nonprime[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" Enter #%d element of the set: ",i+1);
        if (scanf("%d", &integers[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid entry\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("\n The set is: {");
    for(i = 0;i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ",integers[i]);
    }
    printf("}");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (isprime(integers[i])) {
            prime[primecnt++] = integers[i];
        } else {
            nonprime[nonprimecnt++] = integers[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\n Prime numbers: { ");
    for(i = 0; i < primecnt; i++) {
        printf("%d ", prime[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n Non prime numbers: { ");
    for(i = 0; i < nonprimecnt; i++) {
        printf("%d ",nonprime[i]);
    }
    printf("} \n");

    return 0;
}

int
isprime(int n) {
    int divisor;
    if (n < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (divisor=2; divisor*divisor<=n; divisor++) {
        if (n%divisor==0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, there are some issues in your code:

1. As says *user2052592*, you exchanged the *left-hand* side of the assignment operator `=` with the right-hand side.
2. You used *the same variable* (`i`) for indexing array `integer[]` as arrays `prime[]` and `nonPrime[]` but *they are not synchronized* (e. g. the 5th integer may be the 2nd prime).
   (What about using directly your `b1` for `nonPrime[]` and `b2` for `prime[]`?)
3. You set your variable `a` for non-primes (by `a = 1`) but you never reset it after using it (by `a = 0`). (*Note*: You chose very nice name for this variable, as for many others.)
4. You logic for deciding if the number is prime is simple but *incorrect*. The inner loop (for `j`) never executes for numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`.

I did *minimal changes in your code* to comprise fixes of these issues.

So please replace the second part of your code with this:

```
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        for(j=2;j<=integer[i-1]-1;j++) {
            if(integer[i-1]%j==0) {
                a=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(a==1  || integer[i-1] == 1) {
            nonPrime[b1]=integer[i-1];
            b1++;
        }
        else {
            prime[b2]=integer[i-1];
            b2++;
        }
        a = 0;
    }
    printf("\n Prime numbers: { ");
    for(i=0;i<b2;i++) {
        printf("%d ",prime[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n Non prime numbers: { ");
    for(i=0;i<b1;i++) {
        printf("%d ",nonPrime[i]);
    }
    printf("} \n");

    return 0;
}
```

I tested it and now it works OK. In spite of it is ugly - but predominantly yours, so you will understand it.

Comment: Great thanks. But j<=integer[i-1]-1 makes the loop unnecessarily goes longer because the divisors of integer[i-1] are not gonna be greater than integer[i-1]/2.

Comment: You are welcome. In general you are right, but if your user will not intentionally enter great number of *huge primes* (greater than 1 million) it doesn't matter. As I said, it was "quick-fix" of your code.

Comment: Please consider to accept my answer (click on the check mark) if it was useful for you (2 reputation for you).

Answer (score 0):

Check LHS & RHS in

```
integer[i-1]=nonPrime[i-1] 
integer[i-1]=prime[i-1]
```